# SQLite: [Single connection + Multiple attaches] vs. [Multiple connections]

Tags: sqlite

In my desktop app I need to work with several (2-10) databases (using the sqlite C/C++ Interface) which all have identical schemas. I have two options: open a single connection with any of these databases, and then `ATTACH` the rest of databases, or I can open a separate connection per each database. Would there be any difference in performance? Also, SQLite [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) mentions there are limits on the number of attached DBs, but never mentions limits on the number of open connections (to different databases).

From the standpoint of coding convenience, the second option seems more advisable: with multiple connections, I might just pass corresponding sqlite3* object to functions that perform queries, without any modifications in these functions. But with attached databases, I'll have to prepend database names to tables, which is more cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are modifying data and have attached databases, SQLite needs to manage a separate [master journal](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html). So ATTACHing is likely to be slower.

You need ATTACH only if you want to access data from multiple databases in the same query.